# VBA - Looping through all ListObjects across a range of worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting, listobject

I have a table conditional formatting macro (thanks Jeeped) that I would like to expand to loop through all tables across a range of worksheets. I suspect this is not the most efficient approach but the its the best I could cobble together, and even then it's not working. So far I'm stuck at two points below. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

1) Setting ws to equal multiple worksheet codenames (e.g. `Set ws = Worksheets(5,6,7)`)

2) Setting the range w/o a run-time error `Set myRange = ws.ListObjects.DataBodyRange` produces "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"

Current code is:

```
Sub ConditionalFormatting()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
    Dim myRange As Range

    Set ws = Worksheet(5) 'Would like to expand to include multiple worksheets!
    Set myRange = ws.ListObjects.DataBodyRange

    For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
        With lo.FormatConditions
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            Call FormatRange(myRange, 10, "$E5=INDEX(Location,1,1)") 'Warehouse1
            Call FormatRange(myRange, 10, "$E5=INDEX(Location,2,1)") 'Warehouse2
            Call FormatRange(myRange, 10, "$E5=INDEX(Location,3,1)") 'Warehouse3
        End With
    Next lo
End Sub

Public Sub FormatRange(r As Range, clr As Integer, frml As String)
    r.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=frml
    r.FormatConditions(r.FormatConditions.Count).Font.colorindex = clr

    With r.FormatConditions(1).Borders(xlTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = color
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With r.FormatConditions(1).Borders(xlBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = color
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    r.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Untested:

```
Sub ConditionalFormatting()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim i


    For Each i in Array(5, 6, 7)

        Set ws = Worksheets(i)     

        For Each lo In ws.ListObjects

            Set myRange = lo.DataBodyRange

            myRange.FormatConditions.Delete
            FormatRange myRange, 10, "$E5=INDEX(Location,1,1)" 'Warehouse1
            FormatRange myRange, 10, "$E5=INDEX(Location,2,1)" 'Warehouse2
            FormatRange myRange, 10, "$E5=INDEX(Location,3,1)" 'Warehouse3

        Next lo

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. This code works but only partially. In my actual file, I have many worksheets in the array--not just three. The code works perfectly for some worksheets in the array, applies formatting but doesn't delete existing format conditions for others, and doesn't apply formatting or delete existing formatting conditions for still others. To get it working in the immediate term, I used `Set ws = ActiveSheet` and ran on every worksheet, which worked. No idea why it's treating the worksheets differently.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you loop over the listobject collection "Listobjects", you can loop over the Worksheet collection "WorkSheets"

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    '...
Next ws
```

Answer (score 0):

used this sample for my code to reset filter of all my tables

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lo As ListObject

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
        If lo.ShowAutoFilter Then
            If lo.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
                lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            End If
        End If
    Next lo
Next ws
```